# Django How to make form fit HTML input field

Tags: python, html, django

I have a small question.

Here is my "Register page":
[![Register page][1]][1]

But when I add my form to the login, for example, I get this:

[![Page with login][2]][2]

I want to know how can I make that form box fit that HTML input field?
I don't know if I have to resize it in the forms.py or if there was a way for it to always bind up the input size that is in the HTML file.

This is the HTML:

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html> 

        {% csrf_token %}

        <html lang="en">
  <head>
    
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>IPV QS Tool Registration</title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="registration.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/style_register.css' %}" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="POST" action="">
      <label>
        <p class="label-txt">ENTER YOUR AMAZON EMAIL</p>
        <input type="email" class="input" required />
        <div class="line-box"></div>
          <div class="line"></div>
        </div>
      </label>
      <label>
        <p class="label-txt">ENTER YOUR AMAZON LOGIN</p>
        {{form.username}}
        <div class="line-box">
          <div class="line"></div>
        </div>
      </label>
      <label>
        <p class="label-txt">CREATE A PASSWORD</p>
        <input
          type="password"
          class="input password"
          pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}"
          title="Must contain at least one  number and one uppercase and lowercase letter, and at least 8 or more characters"
          required
        />
        <div class="line-box">
          <div class="line"></div>
        </div>
      </label>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="registration.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Forms.py:

```
class createUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are missing class="input" from your input field. Please try this,

```
username = forms.CharField(max_length=100,
                       widget= forms.TextInput
                       (attrs={'class':'input'}))
```

**widget= forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'input'})**

It will result in addition of this class to your CharField.

I hope this helps. Feel free to connect in case if the issue still persists.

Thanks.

Comment: Man, can I buy you a drink? This was such a clear and straight forward answer! thank you very much <3 , I was getting confused all the time

Comment: Haha..cant say no to that :) Glad to be of help